# How to have selection and popup details view of ReactJS web app content

Tags: reactjs

I am printing on screen response which has list of names.

I want to have feature of Clicking/Selecting on each item (name), will take to next screen or popup to show detailed content view.

The following code used to display list of names on screen.

```
export default class ItemLister extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: []
  }

componentDidMount() {

    axios
        .get('https://xx.yyy.zzz/xxx/xxxyyyzzz’, {

            headers: {
                'authorization':'Bearer XXXXXXXXX’,
                'cache-control':'no-cache',
                'content-type':'application/xxx.yyy.xxx.v1+json',
                'X-Api-Key': ‘XXXXXXXXX’,
            },
            withCredentials: true
        })
        .then(response => {            
            console.log(response.data)
            this.setState({ result: response.data });            
        }) 
        .catch (err => {
          console.log(err)
        });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        { this.state.result &&
          this.state.result.audiences &&
          this.state.result.audiences.map(person => <li>{person.name}</li>)
        }
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

This is working. Listing down the names on screen in browser. How to make each item(name) as selectable item, and clicking/selecting on each item will popup with detailed content view or navigate to another page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an onClick handler to each list item and in your handler method, you can perform any action you wish to perform when you click an item on the list.

```
   export default class ItemLister extends React.Component {
      state = {
        persons: [],
        currentPersonItem:{},
        showPopup: false
       }

     componentDidMount() {
         // Your api call

       }
     handlePersonItemClick = (person) => {
        return () => {
           this.setState({ showPopup: true,currentPersonItem:person} )
        } 
     }

     render() {
      const { showPopup, currentPersonItem } = this.state 
      return (
       <React.Fragment>
         { showPopup && <Popup person={currentPersonItem} />}
         // Popup is a component you would have to implement
         // you can also make the Popup accept a showPopup prop and you 
         // would only have do <Popup person={currentPersonItem} showPopup={showPopup} />
         <ul>
           { this.state.result &&
             this.state.result.audiences &&
             this.state.result.audiences.map(person => { 
             return (
                <li 
                 onClick={this.handlePersonItemClick(person)}
                >
                 {person.name}
                </li>
             )
            })
           }
         </ul>
       </React.Fragment>
      );
     }
   }
```

Comment: Hi Rex, thank you. As i already mentioned, when i select list item, it should open (Popup like view) popup content page to show some specific contents. How should have such Popup content view click on each item?

Comment: Hi Stella, I don't fully understand your question but I have updated the answer above. I hope you find it useful. Please reach out if you need further clarification.